# Azure diagnotics settings (preview)

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Im new to Azure. I have an App service that has Application Insight enabled. Im trying now to understand what Diagnotics Settings is and what it can be used for.

It seems like most of what Diagnotics Settings does can be done through Application Insights.
Is this correct or am I misunderstanding the purpose behind Diagnotics Settings?

Comment: Also, do not forget to mark questions as answered if you think it solved your issue, see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some (major) differences. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings):

> Platform logs in Azure, including the Azure Activity log and resource logs, provide detailed diagnostic and auditing information for Azure resources and the Azure platform they depend on. Platform metrics are collected by default and typically stored in the Azure Monitor metrics database.

Now, when we are talking about auditing information and activity logs, that is something that Application Insights (AI) cannot do. Also, AI is geared towards applications whereas Diagnostics Settings is used to emit information about **azure platform resources**. AI allows you to send custom telemetry and also can track a lot more detailed information.

I assume you ask this question in the context of an Azure Web App or Azure Function. I'd recommend to enable both. AI has a lot more to offer than Diagnostics Settings when it comes to detailed information about how your **application** is behaving.